# How to send additional form fields using jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jquery file upload to upload files to server side action. However, I would like to also send additional form fields as part of the form submit. Additionally, I want the formsubmit to happen only when the "submit" button is clicked.

Is this doable using jquery file upload?

I've created a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/mozujilede/1/edit?html,js,output

**Desired behavior:**

- user should be alerted if they try to upload more files than allowed limit
- additional form data should be sent to the server side along with multiple files
- the form submit should happen only when user clicks submit button.

This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
var maxFiles = 10;
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    singleFileUploads: false,
    url: '/uploadUrl'
}).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        var input = $('#input');
        data.formData = {example: input.val()};
        var fileCount = data.files.length;
        if (fileCount > maxFiles) {
            alert("The max number of files is "+maxFiles);
            return false; 
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can use `FormData` to `POST` N files and additional key, value pairs to server.

Comment: How can I only send stuff to server when submit is clicked. at the moment the submission seems to be happening soon as I upload files

Comment: Have not tried `jquery-file-upload`. You should be able to achieve requirement by preventing default action at click at `<input type="submit">` of `<form>` and `POST`ing `form` elements key, value pairs to server using `FormData` and `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```js
var byButton = false;
$("#sub-but").on("click",function(){
  var inp = $("#files")[0];
  if(inp.files.length > 10){
    alert("Max number of files");
    return false;
  }
  byButton = true;
  $("#myForm").submit();
});
function validate(){
  if(!byButton)
     return false;
  byButton = false;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return validate();">
  <input type="text" placeholder="some extra items"/>
  <input type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple"/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub-but"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Does code prevent default action of `<form>` submission at click at `<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub-but"/>`?

Comment: From what i tested, if the number of files is more than 10, form is not submitted, So the default action must be prevented.

Comment: @guest271314 You may try by opening the network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: _"From what i tested, if the number of files is more than 10, form is not submitted, So the default action must be prevented."_ Have you clicked `<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub-but"/>`  at stacksnippets?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to submit the form.

Comment: There is no minimum number of files set in the code. So the form submits even if the there are no files. We could write any rule inside the jquery event.